# Why can't I successfully install and then import pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I installed pygame using a .msi file downloading from pygame.org
But when I try to code like

```
import pygame
```

an ImportError raise

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Why is that?

I installed pygame in my python 2 directory, which is ***c:\python27***.

Comment: There are 32- and 64-bit versions of Python; likewise there are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of pygame. The one you installed does not match the bitness of your python. I guess you installed the 32-bit ones, and now need to download the 64-bit ones (yes that `Win32` is very confusing).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  by the way what is win32

Comment: win32 refers to "32-bit Windows"